# Get children to line up centred or middle

Tags: css

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rahjrLny/)

I am attempting to align child elements evenly between left and right. I tried using margin-left and right: auto but nothing happened.

Here is a screen shot of the navigation in question. I have added a border of 1 px around each element so you can see:

[image]

I'd like the nav line items to be centred in comparisson to their parent. So in the image the line items would move to the right a bit to be centred between the parent rectangle, which is an unordered list.

Here is my approximation of the relevant html:

```
<nav>
  <div id="main-nav">
     <ul id="menu-main">
       <li>cats</li>
       <li>dogs</li>
       <li>sheep</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Currently relevant (I think) CSS is:

```
#main-navigation {
display: inline;
float: left;} 

#main-navigation div {
display: block;}

#menu-main {
position: relative;
float: left;}

#menu-main li {
float: left;
}
```

Put another way, I'd like to centre floated child elements against the parent. If I zoom in and out with my browser I can see that the nav adjusts and change size with some line items moving between top and bottom row in order to fit.

But is there a way to ensure that, whatever the current size of the nav, the child line items will be centred?

Here's another picture, where I have manually added a margin left to #menu-main.

[image]

Now it looks more centred on my screen right now. But is there a way to auto centre it?

Comment: Well. One of the solutions would be to create a wrapper like "center-wrapper" with ``margin: 0 auto`` and dinamically wrap items that are pushed to the second row using jQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/rahjrLny/1/

You don't need to float your `li` elements, simply set them to `display:inline` . Then you can add `text-align: centre` to your `ul` element, and all should be good.

(You'll need to remove some margins that have appeared in the fiddle due to the changes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm accepting because your solution works in the fiddle. But on my site it's actually still not working. The drop down menus I can see are aligned center, but the top level line items are not. Does anything come to mind? I wonder if there is a setting on the grandparent div or nav elements?

Comment: Do you have a link you could share?

Comment: Here you are: http://tinyurl.com/md6x9fp
Any pointers greatly appreciated. Right now I have margin-left: 130px set on ul#menu-main but I'd like to be able to remove that and have it "auto" center, since the 130px is just me gauging an approximate center

Comment: There's a lot of different CSS rules acting on `ul` and `li` elements - which makes it hard to diagnose on the browser, as styles are probably getting applied to your nested dropdowns too. I would recommend using id and class selectors in your css instead of targeting the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ak63ppqw/21/)

There's some redundant CSS (for example, no need to specify `#main-navigation div {display: block;}` if you don't have any `div` elements inside the `#main-navigation`).

I've gone with `display:inline-block` as opposed to `display:inline` (plus added some colour borders for visual clarity). Please bear in mind I'm working with the code you supplied in the question rather than building the code from the screenshots.

```
nav {display:inline-block; width:100%;}

#main-nav {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
} 

ul#menu-main {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#menu-main li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT:** I answered this question before I observed there was a fiddle supplied, and worked instead from the code supplied in the question. This may not be the right answer for OP but I'm going to leave it alone for now as I believe it gives a valid example of how one could approach the task of centering a nav list.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I only went with sooks' answer because his was first, no other reason. Thanks again.